# Can I use a derivative in my SDE's advection function?

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose that I have the following SDE:
$$\frac{d\mathbf{x}(t)}{dt}=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}(t)) + \boldsymbol{\eta}(t),$$ where $\boldsymbol{\eta}(t)$ is white noise and $\mathbf{f}(\cdot)$ is an advection function. I'm wondering if I can use $dt$ in the function $\mathbf{f}(\cdot)$. For example, would something like the following be ok?
$$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}(t),dt) = \mathbf{s}(\mathbf{x}(t)) - \mathbf{s}(\mathbf{x}(t-dt))$$
Here, $\mathbf{s}(\mathbf{x}(t))$ denotes the covariates of $\mathbf{x}(t)$. Would having $dt$ in the function $\mathbf{f}(\cdot)$ be problematic in any way, or is this a "legal" move? Also, is there a name for this type of SDE or a place that you can point me to for further reading on this type of SDE?

I suppose that an alternative way to ask this is, "can we have the advection component be a function of the covariates of $d\mathbf{y}(t)$?" For example, can we let $\bf{f}(\cdot)=\bf{f}(\mathbf{s}(d\mathbf{y}))$? Then, upon discretizing, we'd get
$$\frac{\mathbf{x}(t) - \mathbf{x}(t-dt)}{dt} = \mathbf{s}(\mathbf{x}(t)) - \mathbf{s}(\mathbf{x}(t-dt)) + \text{noise}$$

Comment: First to be clear SDEs are really integrations i.e. $$X_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}f(X_{s})ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma (X_{s})dB_{s}$$

and so the $dt$ is just there to denote the integration procedure. Therefore, one way to intepreet $f(X_{s},ds)$ is as a measure i.e. 

$$X_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}f(X_{s})\mu(ds)+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma (X_{s})dB_{s}$$ for some measure $\mu$ that you choose eg. see here 

"Stable process with singular drift" https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030441491400057X

Comment: and here "One-dimensional stochastic differential equations with generalized and singular drift" https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414913001841

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thank you for the comments and links, Thomas. I'll read those shortly. I did not consider interpreting $f(X_s,ds)$ as a measure. That's a good start. If $\mathbf{s}$ is $n$-dimensional, can I extend your measure idea to $n$-dimensions?

Comment: @ThomasKojar In my particular case, I am most interested in looking at specific changes in time, so the integral expression (while the correct expression for SDEs) does not work as intuitively as the Langevin equations for me. Am I correct in thinking that your integral equations are the integral formulation of my desired Langevin equation?

Comment: well then you are really in the SPDE world. But yes, even there, all the equations are meant in integral-form since the white noise is only defined as a distribution i..e integrated against test functions.

Comment: If you haven't already, I would go through Da Prato-Zabczyk's book "Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions" https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/stochastic-equations-in-infinite-dimensions/6218FF6506BE364F82E3CF534FAC2FC5

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thanks for the book recommendation. I was planning to go through Holden et al.'s SPDE book, but I will check that one out instead (or in conjunction). Thank you for your help.